# CSS methodical way to use percentages of ancestor nodes?

Tags: css, css-float

I'm looking for a general best practice for responsive design, when modules are nested in HTML. Are there standard properties like `display` and `position` that allow `width/height/left/top/right/bottom` properties to be passed onto children? Are `float/clear` used to provide fresh slates for children?

In my example, this would mean using percentage widths of the `#main` ancestor for each `<img>` inside an `<a>` tag. Right now, my percentage seems to be based on the sibling text width and corresponding CSS table cell width.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Are there standard properties like display and position that allow width/height/left/top/right/bottom properties to be passed onto children?

You cannot pass parent properties to the children but you sure can `inherit` from the parent it, e.g. using `position:inherit` in the children element you can inherit whatever value the parent had for position.

Now for widths and heights you have to use percentage. In your case you are using `display:inline-block` on the anchor tag which behaves almost like using `display:block` with `float:left;` but I don't see you using any width property.

Try this:

```
#main-work .section{
    display:inline-block;
    width: calc(100%/3);
}
```